# How to toggle visibility of console pane or hide it in PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I've started using PowerShell ISE. It shows two panes at start-up namely script pane and console pane. While writing the PowerShell script I don't want to see the console pane. Console pane is relevant only when I try to debug or run my script else it takes up unnecessary screen space. Is there any way to toggle the visibility of console pane?

[image]

There is an option though to toggle script pane using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. I need a similar option to toggle the visibility of console pane

Comment: At the top, there is a button to enable the script pane and set its orientation. From the second last group, it are the 3 icons (right of the powershell icon). The first is show the script pane above the console, the middle button is: show the script pane at the right, and the third button is for not showing the script pane. While this is set to vertical orientation (middle), you can move the divider bar so you see most of the script and little of the console window. This is the best Powershell can do, unless you don't use Powershell ISE at all.

Comment: Powershell uses textfiles, so... Maybe editing it with notepad++??

Comment: LPChip, use Notepad++, instead of the built-in ISE? Why? You can't get syntax highlighting, intelligence or debug, well, unless you add the PowerShell addons to notepad++, but why do that extra work. Unless you are a notepad++ fan. Either what, there is VSCode (cross platform) editor for PowerShell development and way more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the menu at the top of the GUI or keyboard shortcuts. Either way, the moment you run any line, that console is the output window, so, you are going to find your self constantly closing it after each run. I do this maximized script pane daily. So, just saying.

[Keyboard Shortcuts for the Windows PowerShell ISE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/keyboard-shortcuts-for-the-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-6)

Here's a quick way of dumping all ISE keyboard shortcuts, yet know that there are a lot of them are undocumented:

```
# Show ISE shortcuts

(New-Object System.Resources.ResourceManager GuiStrings,$($psISE.GetType().Assembly)).GetResourceSet((Get-Culture),$true,$true) | 
where Name -match 'Shortcut\d?$|^F\d+Keyboard' | 
Sort-Object Value | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
```

I have the above in my profile as a function, when I need to look for one quickly.

```
Function Get-IseKeyBoardShortcuts
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias('giks')]

    Param
    (
       [string[]]$Filter
    )

    (New-Object System.Resources.ResourceManager GuiStrings,$($psISE.GetType().Assembly)).GetResourceSet((Get-Culture),$true,$true) | 
    where Name -match 'Shortcut\d?$|^F\d+Keyboard' | 
    Where Name -Match $Filter | 
    Sort-Object Value | 
    Format-Table -AutoSize 
}

# Example 1
giks

# Example 2
giks -Filter pane
```

for your use case, you should only need the following...

- Maximize Script Pane --- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>
- Go to Script Pane    --- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
- Show Script Pane     --- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- Hide Script Pane     --- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- Go to Command (v2) or Console (v3 and later) Pane --- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for helping. `Ctrl` + `3` is what I was looking for. So there are three visibility states for script editor i.e. split horizontally, split vertically and maximized.

Comment: No worries, and correct. I have a quad monitor display (3, 27inch wide screen attached on my 17inc laptop), so, I've gotten mostly out of that maximize script pane approach, by stretching the ISE across two screens. The script pane is in one and the console in the other. The only time I deal with one screen thus forcing the maximize, is when I am teaching a class, or working a gig at a customer site. Even on the standalone 17inch going side by side is still not so annoying. Thoug I do carry a USB 15inch portable. Anything smaller, well, you know.